# manually set Firebase Firestore cache

Tags: android, kotlin, caching, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I am looking for a solution for my problem, i have a chat app which displays all the users correspondence as a Recyclerview a listener, in-order to improve user experience when a user send a message i manually update the Recyclerview with the current list plus the new message with an "uploading indication" then when the message actually uploads to Firebase the listener overrides the local list i used and updates the last message to "uploaded", problem is if i rebuild the activity the listener automatically update the Recyclerview's list to the one cached therefore the user cannot see his "uploading" message any more until it hits the server.
is was thinking if there is a manually way i can set the listener's cache to the local list without waiting for it to upload? if not maybe there is a better solution i hadn't thought about? (i have many different chats with many different users so i need to be able to fetch every chat channels own unique list)

[image: uploading message only local and uncached]

[image: and uploaded message as overwritten by listener]

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in which you can force a query to retrieve data only from the cache. If this is what you need, you can achieve this with the help of the [DocumentReference.get(Source source)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source)) and [Query.get(Source source)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source)) methods.

> By default, `get()` attempts to provide up-to-date data when possible by waiting for data from the server, but it may return cached data or fail if you are offline and the server cannot be reached. This behavior can be altered via the Source parameter.

So you can pass as an argument to the `DocumentReference` or to the `Query` the source so we can force the retrieval of data from the `server only`, `chache only` or attempt server and fall back to the cache.

So something like this will do the trick:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference docIdRef = db.collection("tests").document("fOpCiqmUjAzjnZimjd5c");
docIdRef.get(Source.CACHE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        //Get data from the documentSnapshot object
    }
});
```

In this case, we force the data to be retrieved from the cache only. If you want to force the data to be retrieved from the server only, you should pass as an argument to the `get()` method, `Source.SERVER`. More informations [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Source).

Comment: i see but is it possible to to add to the cache data if i am offline?

Comment: [For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence). While offline, everything you do in that period of time is added to the cache.